# Using User Profile Service from a different farm

Tags: 2010, user-profile-service, user

This is SP2010. Our production farm has a somewhat-working (sync doesn't work, of course) User Profile Service application. Our test/dev farm doesn't have a User Profile Service app, and I'm a bit paranoid about trying to run both a test/dev UPS and a production UPS against the same AD domain. The only reason I'm tinkering with it at all is so I can make use of Audience Targeting in my sites.

Does anybody have experience with publishing UPS on Farm "A" and subscribing to it on Farm "B"? In my dream scenario, it not only works, but Farm "B" doesn't mess up one little thing on Farm "A"'s setup.

Or to rephrase so that this is a specific question, *if I publish UPS from Farm "A", and subscribe to it on Farm "B", will it work to the point where Audience Targeting will then work on Farm "B"'s sites?* (really, will it work at all?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this should all work (though I wouldn't recommend having connections between a development and production environment).

With farms that consume a service application from another farm, the service application provides all the same functionality as if it was on that farm (from a consumption point of view, you can still only manage it on the farm it is actually on).

Any audience configuration in your UPA would be available to a consuming farm.

BTW: Microsoft has great documentation on how to accomplish this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff621100(v=office.14).aspx