# Delegate control user profile service

Tags: user-profile-service

We are running sp 2010 in production, we are testing sp 2013. We only have one AD. Is there a potenial problem running the UPS on the same ad?

Answer (score 0):

This should all work. You can run UPS on Same AD there is no harm. If you are using same UPS across farms then you need to check :

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff621100(v=office.14).aspx

[Using User Profile Service from a different farm](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/60663/using-user-profile-service-from-a-different-farm)